# Aspect ratio not found when listing video from Youtube API V3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Currently, I am using Youtube API V3 to get the video information including field fileDetails.videoStreams. To ensure that it's authenticated by owner using Oauth2.

But, I cannot find aspect_ratio in API response of some videos.
Please see the screenshot below:
[image]

Does everyone know how to resolve this issue?

I really appreciate your help.